# A problem about the special case of the Vitali-Caratheodory theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, suppose there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{R}$ in $X$ which contains all Borel sets in $X$, and there exists a positive measure $\mu$ on $\mathscr{R}$
 which has the following additional properties:

(a) $\mu(K)<\infty$ for every compact set $K\subset X$.

(b) For every $E\in \mathscr{R}$, we have
$$\mu(E) = \inf\, \{\mu(V): E\subset V, V \mathrm{ open}\}$$.

(c) The relation

$$\mu(E) = \sup\,\{\mu(K): K\subset E, K \mathrm{ compact}\}$$

holds for every open set $E$, and for every $E\in \mathscr{R}$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$.

Suppose $f\in L^1(\mu)$, $f$ is real-valued, and $\epsilon>0$. Does there exist functions $u,v:X\to \Bbb R$ on $X$ such that $u\le f\le v$, $u$ is upper semicontinuous and bounded above, $v$ is lower semicontinuous and bounded below, and $\int_X(v-u)\,d\mu<\epsilon$?

[Let $f$ be a real (or extended-real) function on a topological space. If
$$\{x:f(x) >\alpha\}$$
is open for every real $\alpha$, $f$ is said to be lower semicontinuous. If
$$\{x:f(x) < \alpha\}$$
is open for every real $\alpha$, $f$ is said to be upper semicontinuous.]

Comment: Your thoughts?  Is it true for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$?